# bootstrap 3 have two buttons aligned in the same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i have the following html code, and i use bootstrap 3. What i try to achieve is to have the 4 buttons with the klasse text, be the first two in the same row, and the next two, in the next row. Now each button is shown in its own row.

How the below code should be altered?

```html
<div class="background-image background-image--attachment-scroll" style="background-image: url(http://sitefront.png);">&nbsp;</div>

<div class="background-image-overlay region--dark-typography region--white-background" style="opacity: 0.0;background-size:contain;">&nbsp;</div>


<div class="container-fluid region--dark-typography region--white-background">
  <div class="clearfix block block-block-content block-block-content58f3bb9a-975d-4cef-bb21-a0e3d14ec934" id="block-howprofessionalisourstaff">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item">
        <div class="row bottom-spacing-medium">
          <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
            <div class="row bottom-spacing-medium">
              <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
                <div class="bottom-spacing-large">
                  <p class="text-center"><a class="button" href="http://site/">klasse 1</a><a class="button" href="http://site">klasse 2</a><a class="button" href="http://site/">klasse 3</a><a class="button" href="http://site/">klasse 4</a></p>
                </div>

                <div class="scroll-button smooth-scroll"><a href="#page-start"><span class="sr-only">Content start</span></a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with all suggested solutions, is that when i use the following drupal theme button class, it does not force buttons to be on the same row, when i have for instance text as large as the following in all buttons:
Use Bootstrap’s custom button styles for actions in forms...
https://www.drupal.org/project/showcase_lite

Comment: buttons needs to look like plain text or as actual buttons?

Comment: they need to look like actual buttons

Comment: So keeping your code, I have edited my answer, adding "btn btn-default" classes for the buttons, however I think both other answers are actually a better and cleaner solution

Answer (score 2):

you need something like this

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://site/">klasse 1</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://site">klasse 2</a>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://site/">klasse 3</a>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://site/">klasse 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you would like to achieve, please let me know, if not I'll give you more solutions:

Basically I have deleted button klasse3 & klasse4 from the "p class text-center" and I have added them into another "p class text-center" below.
This is a simple solution, but I think you could achieve a better result with a different solution

**Actual Button**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="jelly-page">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" />
 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery.css" />      
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/encstyle.css" />      
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css" />  

       
</head>
<body >

 
 <div class="background-image background-image--attachment-scroll" style="background-image: url(http://sitefront.png);">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="background-image-overlay region--dark-typography region--white-background" style="opacity: 0.0;background-size:contain;">&nbsp;</div>


    <div class="container-fluid region--dark-typography region--white-background">
    <div class="clearfix block block-block-content block-block-content58f3bb9a-975d-4cef-bb21-a0e3d14ec934" id="block-howprofessionalisourstaff">
    <div class="content">
    <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item">
    <div class="row bottom-spacing-medium">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
    <div class="row bottom-spacing-medium">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
    <div class="bottom-spacing-large">
    <p class="text-center">
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://site/">klasse 1</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://site">klasse 2</a>
 </p>
  
  <p class="text-center">
  
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://site/">klasse 3</a>
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="http://site/">klasse 4</a></p> 
    </div>
  
  

    <div class="scroll-button smooth-scroll"><a href="#page-start"><span class="sr-only">Content start</span></a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

**Plain text**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="jelly-page">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" />
 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery.css" />      
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/encstyle.css" />      
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css" />  

       
</head>
<body >

 
 <div class="background-image background-image--attachment-scroll" style="background-image: url(http://sitefront.png);">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="background-image-overlay region--dark-typography region--white-background" style="opacity: 0.0;background-size:contain;">&nbsp;</div>


    <div class="container-fluid region--dark-typography region--white-background">
    <div class="clearfix block block-block-content block-block-content58f3bb9a-975d-4cef-bb21-a0e3d14ec934" id="block-howprofessionalisourstaff">
    <div class="content">
    <div class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item">
    <div class="row bottom-spacing-medium">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
    <div class="row bottom-spacing-medium">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
    <div class="bottom-spacing-large">
    <p class="text-center">
  <a class="button" href="http://site/">klasse 1</a>
  <a class="button" href="http://site">klasse 2</a>
 </p>
  
  <p class="text-center">
  
  <a class="button" href="http://site/">klasse 3</a>
  <a class="button" href="http://site/">klasse 4</a></p> 
    </div>
  
  

    <div class="scroll-button smooth-scroll"><a href="#page-start"><span class="sr-only">Content start</span></a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```